# OData with WCF DataService - Adding a custom query option

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

I have a wcf `DataService` and I would like to extend the odata query syntax with a custom query option.

Specifically I'm trying to implement a $groupby option. 
The only example of someone doing this is the `XpoDataService` from DevExpress wich adds a custom [!summary](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/theonewith/archive/2010/08/09/odata-provider-for-xpo-summary-extensions-summary.aspx) extension.
I tried looking at the source but I can't figure out how it works.

Even implementing my own DataService the only extension point seems to be the IQueryable that gets returned from the IDataServiceQueryProvider but that seems to be of no help.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think WCF Data Service provides an opening to support this kind of extension (unless you write your own Data Services Provider).

From my side I developed the QueryByCube method (www.adaptivelinq.com) to perform an implicit aggregation on an IQueryable collection. In fact, this amounts to write a LINQ provider. The advantage is that it applies to any .Net collection (supporting GroupBy) and not only in the context of an OData service.